# Error MSB3086: Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath ""

Tags: msbuild

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2428,5):
>   Error MSB3086: Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath ""
>   or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed"

I tried to install windows sdk v8.0A. but the installation process was rolling back. I m using os window 10

I am using VS 2017 framework version 4.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error MSB3086: Task could not find “LC.exe” using the SdkToolsPath “”

To resolve this issue, please try to following troubleshootings:

- Using the `MSBuild.exe` from Visual Studio 2017 instead of .net framework. The location of MSBuild in Visual Studio 2017 should be:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
  ```
- Specify the path to the SDK directly in the .csproj file:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools</TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```

  or pass `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory` as a parameter to avoid having to edit your `.csproj` files

  ```
  MSBuild.exe mysolution.sln /t:build /p:TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools"
  ```
- Set a flag to tell MSBuild to ignore it:

  ```
  /p:GenerateSerializationAssemblies=Off
  ```
- Try to re-install the Visual Studio 2017.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup ,i tried with adding a "TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory" tag in csproj . it worked fine for me! Thank you @Leo Liu-MSFT